# (c++) reading from a text file

Tags: c++

I made this program that asks users to enter the grade of some students, determine whether they pass or fail and then determine how many pass and how many fail the exam. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int passing = 0;
    int failing = 0;

    int mid_grade;
    int final_grade;

    int student = 5;


    while (student > 0)
    {   
        cout << "Enter mid-term grade: ";
        cin >>  mid_grade;

        cout << "Enter final grade: ";
        cin >> final_grade;

        double total_grade = (double)mid_grade*3/10 + (double)final_grade*7/10;;
        cout << "The total grade is: " << total_grade << endl;
        student --;

    if (mid_grade < 4 || final_grade < 4 || total_grade < 10)
        {
//          cout << "Fail." << endl;
            failing++;
        }
    else 
        {
//          cout << "Pass!" << endl;
            passing++;
        }
    }
    cout << passing << " student passed" << endl;
    cout << failing << " student failed" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

what I want to do now is to tell my program to read the mid-term and the final grade in a text file I made then calculate the total grade (like I did in the above code), then show the grades on the screen, determine who pass and fail the exam and the total number of students who pass/fail the exam. 
Here's what my text file looks like:

```
Mid-term    Final     
8           5
9           6
10          11
15          17
9           20
11          19
```

Comment: Please use 'fstream'.

Comment: What problem are you having? We're not going to write it for you, you have to make an attempt yourself. If you can't get it working, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Please search StackOverflow for "c++ read file struct" or "c++ read file parsing".  There are already a plethora of similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so this should help. I put some notes. You need to create a text file in the same directory /src called grades.txt

should look like this

```
10 9 8 7 4 3 4 5 5 9
```

You will need to change things. But this should give you a good starting point or where you should be going. Hope this helps.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int passing = 0;
    int failing = 0;

    int mid_grade = 0;  //Always initilize your variables!!!
    int final_grade = 0;

    int student = 5;


    //Create a variable to open the file
    ifstream inFile; inFile.open("src\\grades.txt");

    while (student > 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter mid-term grade: ";
        inFile >>  mid_grade;
        cout << mid_grade << endl;

        cout << "Enter final grade: ";
        inFile >> final_grade;
        cout << final_grade << endl;

        cout << "student number" << student << endl; //Notice it goes backwards you have to fix it.
        double total_grade = ((double)mid_grade*3)/10 + ((double)final_grade*7/10);
        cout << "The total grade is: " << total_grade << endl;
        student --;
        cout << endl;

    if (total_grade < 7)
        {
//          cout << "Fail." << endl;
            failing++;
        }
    else
        {
//          cout << "Pass!" << endl;
            passing++;
        }
    }`enter code here`
    cout << passing << " student penter code hereassed" << endl;
    cout << failing << " student failed" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd read the file, skip the 1st line, then read the rest, line by line, using stringtokenizer to get the two values to work with.